# How to terminate bash function execution

Tags: bash

I have several functions in my `.bashrc` and I want to terminate the whole "run" on error. For example:

```
function assert_env()
{
    var_name=$1

    if [ -z "${!var_name}" ]; then
        printf "Missing environment variable: $var_name\n"
        exit 1
    fi
}

function my_test()
{
    assert_env "abc"
    print $abc
}
```

If i type `my_test` in terminal I want to terminate the execution, but this script closes the terminal (as expected - I run `exit 1`).

How may I terminate the execution without closing the current terminal?

EDIT: To be more specific - I don't want to return from `assert_env`, I want my following commands from `my_test` to not be executed if the condition from `assert_env` is not met, something like C++ `assert`

Comment: try `return`--it's a bit like `exit` for functions

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble `return` will return from  `assert_env`, it won't terminate the whole callstack

Comment: You can send a SIGSTOP with  `kill -s 17 $$`, or whichever [signal](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html) fits better for your case

Comment: @Felics: Function defined in `.bashrc` gets executed in the same shell and that's why sending `exit 1` terminates your current shell.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to handle exceptions through function calls in shell. As you said, `exit` will eventually exit the shell, and `return` won't exit function stack.

I would check the return values and manually return on all stack calls.

Comment: Are you actually looking for `: ${abc?Assertion failed}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround - execute the function content in a subshell

Example:

```
function assert_env()
{
    var_name=$1

    if [ -z "${!var_name}" ]; then
        printf "Missing environment variable: $var_name\n"
        exit 1
    fi
}

function my_test()
{
(
    printf "$1\n"

    assert_env "abc"

    printf $abc
)
}
```

Comment: Fun fact, if you have parentheses you don't need curly braces: `my_test() ( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `exit` returns the exit code specified to the shell itself, so using `exit 1` would obviously exit your current shell. You need to use `return` here.

As far as you requirement is considered, just use the exit code from the function `assert_env` to decide if you want to run further statements. Here  using `return` will cause the current function to go out of scope and what ever code you are returning back to the callee can be used to check if its successful/failure

```
function assert_env() {
    local ret_val=0; var_name=$1  

    if [ -z "${!var_name}" ]; then
        printf "Missing environment variable: $var_name\n"
        ret_val=1
    fi

    return ${ret_val}
}
```

Now using it

```
function my_test() {
    if ! assert_env "abc"; then
        return
    fi
    # Or could be just written as assert_env "abc" || return
}
```

This way, if the `assert_env` returns `0`, the if-clause in `my_test` asserts failure and rest of the code gets executed. And on returning `1` the condition becomes true and the function call is returned without exiting the main scipt.

Note that `function` keyword is non-standard and not POSIX compliant and may not work across shells. Just drop the keyword if you want to make it portable.

Comment: +1 Thank you! This works, but it doesn't reduce the code size. Basically I'm replacing one `if` with another `if` and I would like to remove the `if`s in the calling code

Comment: @Felics: Ok the if-conditionals bother you in `my_test` just use `assert_env "abc" || return`